Linux systemd-resolved not answering MulticastDNS
In general, I'm currently replacing all networking stuff with the builtin systemd facilities. NetworkManager, dnsmasq, dhcpcd, avahi-daemon -- all gone, and things seem to be mostly working.
Except that local hostnames aren't resolved from my Desktop box anymore:
C:\Users\Christian>ping fritzwlan
Ping request could not find host fritzwlan. Please check the name and try again.

Now, I can see the queries on the server:
root@gatekeeper:/home/stieber# tcpdump -i lan -p udp
...
15:27:18.381225 IP Desktop.mdns > mdns.mcast.net.mdns: 0 A (QM)? fritzwlan.local. (33)
15:27:18.381506 IP Desktop.mdns > mdns.mcast.net.mdns: 0 AAAA (QM)? fritzwlan.local. (33)
15:27:18.469278 IP gatekeeper.mdns > mdns.mcast.net.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 255.255.1.10.in-addr.arpa. (43)
15:27:18.804129 IP Desktop.61938 > 224.0.0.252.5355: UDP, length 27
15:27:18.804129 IP Desktop.61316 > 224.0.0.252.5355: UDP, length 27
15:27:19.131294 IP Desktop.netbios-ns > 10.1.255.255.netbios-ns: UDP, length 50
15:27:19.383976 IP Desktop.mdns > mdns.mcast.net.mdns: 0 AAAA (QM)? fritzwlan.local. (33)
15:27:19.384990 IP Desktop.mdns > mdns.mcast.net.mdns: 0 A (QM)? fritzwlan.local. (33)
15:27:19.385926 IP Desktop.mdns > mdns.mcast.net.mdns: 0 AAAA (QM)? fritzwlan.local. (33)
15:27:19.610547 IP gatekeeper.mdns > mdns.mcast.net.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 255.255.1.10.in-addr.arpa. (43)

/var/log/syslog doesn't show anything.
As far as I can tell, the systemd-resolved should have multicast enabled:
root@gatekeeper:/home/stieber# resolvectl status
Global
          Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   resolv.conf mode: stub
Fallback DNS Servers 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1

Link 2 (lan)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6 mDNS/IPv4 mDNS/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wan)
...

and
root@gatekeeper:/home/stieber# resolvectl mdns
Global: yes
Link 2 (lan): yes
...
root@gatekeeper:/home/stieber# resolvectl llmnr
Global: yes
Link 2 (lan): yes
...

The config-file also says its fully enabled, and not just resolve:
root@gatekeeper:/home/stieber# cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
...
# lots of comments removed
...
[Resolve]
FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
DNSStubListenerExtra=10.1.1.1:53
DNSStubListenerExtra=127.0.0.1:53
LLMNR=true
MulticastDNS=true

It's not the most terrible problem ever, especially since external hosts resolve just fine, so "the internet" works.
On the server itself, it resolves just fine:
root@gatekeeper:/home/stieber# dig fritzwlan

; <<>> DiG 9.18.24-1-Raspbian <<>> fritzwlan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47502
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fritzwlan.                     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
fritzwlan.              0       IN      A       10.1.1.2

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sun May 05 15:44:02 CEST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54

Multicast is also enabled on the interface:
[Match]
Name=lan

[Link]
Multicast=true

[Network]
Address=10.1.1.1/16
DHCPServer=yes
MulticastDNS=true
LLMNR=true

[DHCPServer]
...

Based on comments:
root@gatekeeper:/home/stieber# ss -lpn 'sport = :5353 or sport = :5355'
Netid             State              Recv-Q             Send-Q                         Local Address:Port                          Peer Address:Port             Process
udp               UNCONN             0                  0                                    0.0.0.0:5353                               0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=1626,fd=15))
udp               UNCONN             0                  0                                    0.0.0.0:5355                               0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=1626,fd=11))
udp               UNCONN             0                  0                                          *:5353                                     *:*                 users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=1626,fd=16))
udp               UNCONN             0                  0                                          *:5355                                     *:*                 users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=1626,fd=13))
tcp               LISTEN             0                  4096                                 0.0.0.0:5355                               0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=1626,fd=12))
tcp               LISTEN             0                  4096                                    [::]:5355                                  [::]:*                 users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=1626,fd=14))

So it seems the thing is listening on these ports. No idea how the "multicast" plays into this, though.
Same with firewall: towards "LAN", it should be completely open:
root@gatekeeper:/home/stieber# nft list ruleset
        chain output-rejects {
                oifname "wan" tcp dport { 25, 110, 143 } reject
        }

        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority 100; policy accept;
                jump output-rejects
        }
...
table inet filter {
...
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
                ct state invalid drop
                icmp type echo-request limit rate over 2/second drop
                ip protocol icmp accept
                iif { "lo", "lan" } accept
...

But, I must admit, I don't know yet how multicast factors into this...

So, right now, I'm rather confused as to where to look... any ideas?

firewall settings?

Did you confirm that something's listening on 5353/UDP?

@TomYan good idea; I'll have to look into whether multicast needs some special handling. Nft is almost completely open towards the "LAN".
@Spiff I added an ss output suggesting that not just something but actually systemd-resolved does.

I think it's best to share full output of nft list ruleset (and maybe also iptables-save). Btw, I just notice that in the dig output, the name was resolved to 10.1.1.2, while you .network file configure the interface with 10.1.1.1. Did you change the IP in the middle?

And your shell prompt seems to indicate that the hostname is gatekeeper?

@TomYan While I'm not entirely sure what made you ask this, it's an extremely interesting thing -- I've been casually ssh-ing to the box al the time, even though putty uses the name gatekeeper to access it... and when I do the tcpdump, it actually DOES reply to the gatekeeper-query, just not to the other ones... so that might actually be something to investigate...

I faced this same issue, in the end it turned out that the OS upgrade installed firewalld which apparently came configured out of the box to block/filter mDNS.
